# What's the simplest way of automatically activating/verifying user accounts?

Tags: users

I'd like to have my users automatically verified/activated so they can immediately login after registration. Normally this would be done through the automatic emailer, but I'd like to skip that.

Are there any easy changes to do this, or will I have to write a plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Craft Pro edition installed, in the control panel you can go to Settings->Users->Settings and uncheck "Verify email addresses?" and check "Allow public registration?".

Use a front-end registration for similar to [this](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) and it should do what you're looking for.

Comment: I really should've seen that myself. 

Thank you very much!