# Auto log in user

Tags: users, registration, login

I’m setting up a site that has paid membership. For a visitor to create an account I’ll need to:

1. Ask for email and password and create the new user.
2. Take payment and upgrade the user’s status/user group if successful.

This could be part of the same form, or split into two steps. Either way, I’d like to know if it’s possible to auto log in the user once they’ve hit submit on their registration form.

Comment: Does this help: ["What's the simplest way of automatically activating/verifying user accounts"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/7039/125)?

Comment: Sorry, yes I do have that setup. I’ve edited the question to clarify: I’d like to know if it’s possible to auto log in the user once they’ve hit submit on their registration form.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out the [`autoLoginAfterAccountActivation` config setting](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#autoLoginAfterAccountActivation).

To enable it, set it to true in your `craft/config/general.php` file:

```
'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks Ben.