# Need difference sign up path for 2 groups

Tags: plugin-development, users, plugins

I see [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7039/whats-the-simplest-way-of-automatically-activating-verifying-user-accounts#) about automatically activating/verify user accounts. However, I have 2 group of users, 1 group is open public which would like to have automatically activating/verify. The 2nd group is private, need activate email and verify. Should I write a plugin or just modify UsersService.php to split 2 directions on saveUser?

Thanks,
Angela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I write a plugin or just modify UsersService.php to split 2 directions on saveUser?

The first one.  The second one has many drawbacks:

1. Any changes you make in `craft/app` can (and probably will) get overwritten during an update.
2. Which means you'll have to reapply them after updating.
3. It's not supported.

Craft has a bunch of [events](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference) that plugins can listen to and run logic when they fire without hacking core Craft files.  In your case, it sounds like `onBeforeSaveUser` or `onSaveUser` might be what you need.

Comment: Thanks @ Jeremy-daalder @ Damon Sorry @Matt-stein, I didn't pay attention that is a new question. I will do it next time. Thanks for taking care of it.